# String concatentation in html and echo statement

Tags: php, html

So I have this line of code in a php file:

```
echo "<a class='button' onclick=report('$row[id]')></a>";
```

I'd like to add an id to the line, so I tried this:

```
echo "<a class='button' id='"report".$row[id]' onclick=changeColor('$row[id]')></a>";
```

and in my javascript file

```
document.getElementById('report'+id).style.color('blue');
```

but I keep getting errors in javascript

> cannot read property 'style' of null,

because I'm doing something wrong with the concatenation. I'm trying to get the id to be something like "report100" by concatenating it with $row[id] and then in the javascript file, change it's font color. I've tried other variations, but I just seem to get it right.

Comment: you getting id correctly in js ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the error cannot read property 'style' of null, which I think points to where I'm doing the concatenation

Comment: The PHP code already gives an error ***"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'report' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'"***. You have to enable error reporting and logging in PHP already and then track for such errors. PHP then tells you where you've made a little mistake: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456). Working with strings in PHP is also well outlined in the PHP manual her: http://php.net/string - good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this.

```
echo "<a class='button' id='report".$row['id']."' onclick=changeColor(".$row['id'].")></a>";
```

**UPDATE :**

To concatenate a string and variable together, use the string concatenation operator `.` (a dot).

As well it is depend on how you start the string

Starting the string with `''` (single quotes) will be

```
echo '<a class="button" id="report'.$row['id'].'">';
```

Starting the string with `""` (double quotes) will be

```
echo "<a class='button' id='report'".$row['id'].">";
```

Answer (score 0):

The to prevent the `"` from terminating the string, you can use `\"`.

```
echo "<a class=\"button\" id=\"report$row[id]\" onclick=\"changeColor('$row[id]')\"></a>";
```

Should result in

```
<a class="button" id="report100" onclick="changeColor('100')"></a>
```